# How can I make the font data BOLD for data titles on the horizontal axis in google charts?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

The help that I received from other users on this forum didn't help at all ... I have a chart that is generated through google charts API on this link http://imageshack.us/f/9/capturesfn.png/

However, the titles of the data on this column chart are so small and hard to read .. How can I make it so those labels on the horizontal axis can be bold and the fonts can be changed ???  The answers I got didn't help

Below I did this but it doesnt seem to work .. where I am going wrong ?  the data labels on the horizontal axis stay the same

```
 var options = {width: 1200, height: 800, hAxis: {textStyle: {color: 'black', fontName: 'Arial Black',fontSize: 35},is3D: true,title: 'Orders'};
chart.draw(dataTable, options);
```

Comment: What answers did you get?  Why didn't they help?

Comment: If the font was any larger, the labels would overlap. How do you expect to deal with that? Do you want fewer labels to show? There is considerable information [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes). Did you look there? Does it help? Quoting: "You can customize label positioning and style using the hAxis/vAxis.textPosition and hAxis/vAxis.textStyle options."

Comment: How can I make the fonts just bold then ...can you be show me exactly how I could do that .. I dont want to increase the fonts size

Comment: I have updated my answer with a full example - using a "heavy" font (Arial Black) to get the bold effect. I hope it works for you now!

Answer (score 4):

Original answer:

```
var options = {
  hAxis: {textStyle: {
    color: 'black', 
    fontName: 'Arial Black', 
    fontSize: 16
  };

chart.draw(data, options)
```

Might be of some help...

**EDIT**
Full example (can be found at http://www.floris.us/SO/boldChart.html as well):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Bold font demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chango">
    <script>
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

      function plotChart(){
        // create some dummy data
        var myData = [["x","y"],[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,2]];
        // turn it into a table:
        var myChartData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(myData);
        // create the empty charts:
        var normalPlot = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('normalChart'));
        var boldPlot = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('boldChart'));    

        // create options for chart with bold labels:
        var chartOptionsBold = {
          title: 'Chart with bold x labels',
          titleTextStyle: {color: 'blue', fontName: 'Arial', fontSize: '18', fontWidth: 'normal'},
          hAxis: {title: 'x', 
            textStyle: {
            fontName: 'Chango', 
            }
          },
          vAxis: {title: 'y values'},
          lineWidth: 1,
          pointSize: 2
        };

        var chartOptionsNormal = {
          title: 'Chart with default axis labels',
          titleTextStyle: {color: 'black', fontName: 'Arial', fontSize: '18', fontWidth: 'normal'},
          hAxis: {title: 'x'},
          vAxis: {title: 'y'},
          lineWidth: 1,
          pointSize: 2
        };

        normalPlot.draw(myChartData, chartOptionsNormal);
        boldPlot.draw(myChartData, chartOptionsBold);

      };
    </script>
    <style>
      div.graphBox {
        height: 400px; width: 600px; 
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body onload="plotChart()">
  <div class="graphBox", id="normalChart">Normal chart goes here</div>
  <div class="graphBox", id="boldChart">Bold chart goes here</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Screen shot of output:

[image]

As you can see, it is possible to change the properties of the axis labels with the example given. I did this with a Safari browser version 6.0.3; also tested with Firefox 21.0 (both on Mac). Also tested on iPhone - similar results.

**Further Edit**

You can make sure that the font you choose is available to the browser using something like this in the header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chango">
```

This particular example makes the font "Chango" available. It is a very heavy font, and thus would "bold" your text quite nicely. Obviously, you need to adjust your `hAxis textStyle` to match whatever font you chose. You can find a selection of fonts at http://www.google.com/fonts/

Answer (score 2):

There is an [option](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes) to make the `hAxis` text bold:

```
options.hAxis.textStyle.bold = true;
```

**OR**

Full options set based on your example:

```
var options = {
  width: 1200,
  height: 800, 
  hAxis: {
    textStyle: {
      color: 'black',
      fontName: 'Arial Black',
      fontSize: 35,
      bold:true
    },
    is3D: true,
    title: 'Orders'
  };
}

chart.draw(dataTable, options);
```